# Make Angular CLI tests run on AppVeyor's Ubuntu image

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, karma-runner, appveyor

I've created a bare `ng new` application that has component tests based off Karma, and e2e tests based off Protractor. When I configure that repository in AppVeyor like this:

```
version: 1.0.{build}
image: ubuntu
stack: node 10

cache:
  - node_modules -> package.json

install:
  - npm ci
  - node --version
  - npm --version

build: off

test_script:
  - npm run lint
  - npm test -- --progress=false
  - npm run e2e
```

I will get [these errors](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/JeroenHeijmans61392/experiments-appveyor-karma/builds/26037162):

```
17 07 2019 08:44:57.074:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
17 07 2019 08:44:57.082:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v3.1.4 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
17 07 2019 08:44:57.083:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
17 07 2019 08:44:57.089:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
17 07 2019 08:44:58.006:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome

17 07 2019 08:44:58.007:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
17 07 2019 08:44:58.007:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: 
17 07 2019 08:44:58.123:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
17 07 2019 08:44:59.031:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome

17 07 2019 08:44:59.032:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
17 07 2019 08:44:59.032:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: 
17 07 2019 08:44:59.411:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
17 07 2019 08:44:59.824:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome

17 07 2019 08:44:59.824:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
17 07 2019 08:44:59.824:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: 
17 07 2019 08:45:00.191:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up.
17 07 2019 08:45:01.776:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
```

[The image contains Google Chrome](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/linux-images-software/#web-browsers) (version 74, currently). I've tried adding

```
- sh: export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

to my AppVeyor file but it did not help.

What do I need to do to run Angular component and e2e tests on AppVeyor's Ubuntu image?

Comment: Initial testing suggests that the `--no-sandbox` flag might be needed to get this working. If I have a fully working example, I will post an answer.